# CakePHP Helpers - Integrating helpers on helpers

Tags: php, cakephp

I created my own helper on CakePHP 2.x that uses the HtmlHelper but it doesn't work, here is the code

```
class NavHelper extends Helper {

   public $helpers = array("Html", "Javascript");

   function __construct($config = array()) {

}

function link($label, $options) {
    if($this->perms(array('controller'=>$options['controller'],'action'=>$options['action']))) {
        $html = '<a ';
        foreach($options as $label => $value) {
            if($label != 'action' || $label != 'controller') {
                $html .= " {$label}=\"{$value}\" ";
            }
            $html .= " href='".$this->Html->url(array('controller'=>$options['controller'],'action'=>$options['action']))."'>".$label."</a>";
        }

        return $html;
    }
    return '';
}
```

> **Fatal error**:  Call to a member function url() on a non-object
>   in
>   **C:\Bitnami\wappstack-5.5.28-0\apache2\htdocs\pokeadmin_v2\app\View\Helper\NavHelper.php** on line **17**

But $this->Html->url worked perfectly on CakePHP 1.3 but on CakePHP 2.x won't work, also tried to use `$this->Html = new HtmlHelper;` with the following error:

> **Warning** (4096): Argument 1 passed to
>   HtmlHelper::__construct() must be an instance of View, none given,
>   called in
>   C:\Bitnami\wappstack-5.5.28-0\apache2\htdocs\pokeadmin_v2\app\View\Helper\NavHelper.php
>   on line 11 and defined [**CORE\Cake\View\Helper\HtmlHelper.php**,
>   line **161**

I also checked the documentation but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You broke the constructor, in two ways that is, first it doesn't accept the arguments required by [**its parent**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.10.1/lib/Cake/View/Helper.php#L212) (view and configuration), and it also never invokes the parent, which is where the required helper map is initialized.

If you don't need the constructor, don't override it, and if you do, make sure that you accept the required arguments and that you pass them on to the parent constructor.

```
public function __construct(View $view, $settings = array()) {
    parent::__construct($view, $settings);
    // ...
}
```

See also **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > Using and Configuring Helpers](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/helpers.html#using-and-configuring-helpers)**

Answer (score 0):

Just found that i can use Router::url for the same action as $this->Html->url

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit off subject, but it might help someone new to CakePHP who happens to stumble across this on here;

You can load Helpers directly on the AppController as such:

```
namespace PluginName\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController as BaseController;
use Cake\Http\Response;
use Cake\Http\ServerRequest;

class AppController extends BaseController
{
    public $helpers = ['PluginName.HelperName'];

    // ....
}
```

Reference: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers.html#loading-helpers-on-the-fly